# Javascript - strange behaviour naming a function 'submit()'

Tags: javascript, html

Is `submit` a reserved word in Javascript?

Take a look at this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function sayHello(){
        console.log('Hello!');
    }

    function submit(){
        console.log('Submit!')
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <button onclick="sayHello()">Say hello</button>
      <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <button onclick="sayHello()">Say hello - outside</button>
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit - outside</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to understand why I can't call the `submit()` function inside the `<form>` tag but it works outside the tag. I think it is a reserved word even because changing the function name the script works well but I can't find any information about that on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar)

I'm not a JS guru, so can someone help me understand this strange behaviour?

Comment: If you are using jQuery (it doesn't look like you are, though), `submit()` is a built-in function.

Comment: Handlers want references.  The `()` are calling the functions immediately.

Comment: @hhoburg No jQuery, vanilla JS

Comment: Really, why the -1?
It's a question about a topic I'd like to know. Meh :(

Comment: People love to downvote. "You don't know enough, but I won't help"

Comment: @evolutionxbox more like "we hate fun. You know your problem is a poorly named function, so just rename the function." That being said, now that I interpret this question as that of mere curiosity, my rating might be milder. Though the downvote button does say "useful", not "interesting"...

Comment: Explain "I can't call the `submit()` function".  Do you get an error?  What is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `submit()` is a built-in function that gets called whenever a `<form>` gets submitted. To have custom functionality kick in which a form is submitted, you'll not only need to use a different function name, but also prevent the default form submission with `event.preventDefault()`, passing the event into the function.

This can be seen in the following -- note that the `sayHello()` will clear the screen (with an attempted form submission), whereas `customSubmit()` will not:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function sayHello(){
        console.log('Hello!');
    }

    function customSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Submit!')
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <button onclick="sayHello()">Say hello</button>
      <button onclick="customSubmit(event)">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <button onclick="sayHello()">Say hello - outside</button>
    <button onclick="customSubmit(event)">Submit - outside</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, a built-in-function, just as I thought. Thank you for your explanation :-)

Comment: @Ema.jar, it's not a builtin per-se. It's just that in that context (within a form), submit is an actual method on that form. You're invoking that `form.submit()` method and not your global `submit()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons inside forms automatically submit the form, as long as the button doesn't have an event handler, or has an event handler that doesn't `preventDefault()`:

```html
<form>
  <button>Say hello</button>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

(see how the form gets submitted - the page in the snippet disappears)

It has nothing to do with the `submit` function name.

But still, using inline event handlers is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.

Inline handlers should be avoided just as much as `eval` should be avoided.

If you want to prevent a button inside a form from submitting the form, call `e.preventDefault()` like this:

```js
function sayHello(){
  console.log('Hello!');
}
function submit(){
  console.log('Submit!')
}
const [b1, b2] = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'));
b1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  sayHello();
});
b2.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  submit();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <button>Say hello</button>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I really appreciate that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pressing a button in a form reloads the page.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Any button in the form will submit the form and reload the page-->
    <form>
      <button id="btn1">Say hello</button>
      <button id="btn2">Submit</button>
      <button>Anything</button>
    </form>

    <!--these ones don't-->
    <button onclick="sayHello()">Say hello - outside</button>
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit - outside</button>
    <script>
      // notice the page loads when we click the 'anything' button, even without an event handler
      //the delay allows you to see it happening

      console.log("loading page...");
      setTimeout(welcome, 500);

      function welcome() {
        console.log("page has been loaded");
      }

      // adding preventDefault to these, stops the form from submitting
      function sayHello(e) {
          console.log('Hello!');
          e.preventDefault();
      }

      function submit(e) {
          console.log('Submit!')
          e.preventDefault();
      }


      //This is how you add event handlers

      let btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
      let btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

      btn1.addEventListener('click', sayHello);
      btn2.addEventListener('click', submit);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```